# Thread-local-storage (__thread) used on a static class member

Tags: c++, class, thread-local-storage

I'm trying thread-local-storage with a C++ class:

```
struct TestTLS
{
    TestTLS()
    {
        TestTLS::g_tls_val = 1;
    }
    
    int getTls()
    {
        return TestTLS::g_tls_val;
    }
    
    void setTls(int v)
    {
        TestTLS::g_tls_val = v;
    }
    
    
private:
    static __thread int g_tls_val;
    
};
```

and then:

```
TestTLS tls;
int ff = tls.getTls();
tls.setTls(3);
int ee = tls.getTls();
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "TestTLS::g_tls_val", referenced from:
      TestTLS::getTls() in main.o
      TestTLS::setTls(int) in main.o
      TestTLS::TestTLS() in main.o
```

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: For one don't use symbols starting with double `__`. They are reservered for compiler/library builders use [thread_local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local) instead.  The actual reason for your comiler error is you declared `static __thread int g_tls_val;` but didn't initalize it anywhere.

Comment: Never ever use things, that start with `__`(2 underscores). Except of few well defined variables(like `__cplusplus`) everything is UB. For thread local variables use `thread_local`

Comment: This has nothing to do with thread local storage, but with an uninstantiated static class member. You'll get the same error without `__thread`. Try it. Fix this without the `__thread`, then add it back in.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I guess it has nothing to do with the thread-local-storage.